# Regression data analysis of CSV file data using R

Tags: r, statistics

I have large data sets in a CSV file which is thousands of server memory usage through out day and months and years. For e.g.

```
serverData <- read.csv("server_mem_usage.csv")
head(serverData)
```

It prints the following:

```
date,server,datatotal(GBs),dataused(GBs)
10 Jun 2014 17:00:50,server1,800,500
10 Jun 2014 19:00:50,server1,800,510
10 Jun 2014 18:00:50,server2,900,815
10 Jun 2014 19:50:50,server2,900,850
```

Now I want to find each server's total and used data. For e.g. in case of server1 total data is 800 and used is 500 and 510 for two dates.

I am not sure how do I analyze this if I create `ts()` it takes only one column how do I apply mapping which will say that for given server find dataused and datatotal for given date range.

I am new to R.

Comment: How will your desired output will look like?

Comment: I want in csv file or graph/plot anything is fine. Not able to figure out ideal output in R. If I write Java program then I can have Map of server name to dataused values.

Comment: I want data for each server for all the date ranges availables for that server in my data sets I have server1 has two dates 10 Jun 2014 17:00:50 and 10 Jun 2014 19:00:50. I want in the end data for each server for all date ranges and dataused and datatotal columns.

Comment: Is the output in my answer is what you are looking for?

Comment: thanks yes that looks good actually in the end what I want is one graph which will tell me server names with the most used data. Can you please guide me how should I get that kind of plotting?

Comment: So you don't need the `datatotal(GBs)` at all, and all you need is to sum `dataused(GBs)` per server and plot it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60316/discussion-between-user449355-and-david-arenburg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what you need, but maybe something like this?

```
library(data.table)
setDT(serverData)[, list(`datatotal(GBs)` = `datatotal(GBs)`[1],
                         `dataused(GBs)`= paste(`dataused(GBs)`, collapse = ", ")),
                  by = list(server)]

##     server datatotal(GBs) dataused(GBs)
## 1: server1            800      500, 510
## 2: server2            900      815, 850
```

So after some discussion in the private chat room, it seems like you need just the list of the servers which reached at least 95% of their capacity per day. One approach will be

```
library(data.table)
temp <- setDT(serverData)[, list(ServerReachedMaxCapacity = any(`dataused(GBs)` >= `datatotal(GBs)`[1]*.95)),
                  by = list(server, Date = as.POSIXct(date,  format = "%d %b %Y"))]
temp2 <- temp[ServerReachedMaxCapacity == T, list(servers = paste(server, collapse = ", ")), by = Date]
```